# NGINX Reverse Proxy PORT

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to implement a reverse proxy with nginx. But with the configuration above what I get is a wrong url in the browser:

```
   http://domain:9080/myLocation/something.html
```

and what I need is (with no port):

```
   http://domain/myLocation/something.html
```

Configuration:

```
location  /myLocation  {
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass  http://xptoserver:9080$request_uri;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host header should never have a port in it.

Change this:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
```

To this:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

Comment: Hi Kyle I change it, and reload the configuration, but I'm still getting the same behaviour. The port is there in the URL

Comment: In that case, the problem doesn't seem to be in the nginx config. More than likely the service you are proxying hard coding the full host and port into the URL based on the config you are giving it.

Comment: Kyle, you were right the backend server was hardcoding the port on the URL! Thanks!